# Unable To Get Live USB To Boot

Tags: grub2, virtual-machine, live-usb, virt-manager

I have a Live USB Debian11 mounted on `sda` Debian10 VM running through `virt-manager`.  How do I get this Live USB to load when I reboot the virtual machine? When grub comes up, I press <kbd>E</kbd>, I get to the grubs screen and see:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-13-amd64
initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-13-amd64
```

I see the Live USB when I load Debian10 VM in the GUI.

**Update:** "Click Boot Options" is what I missed.  So I enabled USB Device on bootup USB `8644:800e` and first rebooted the VM, bootup on `8644:800e` did not save. I then restarted virt-manager.  Same thing `8644:800e` did not boot up.  So I restarted the server and now got:

```
Unable to connect to libvirt qemu:///system

error from service: CheckAuthorization: Did not receive a reply.  Possible causes include: the remote application dod not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

Unable to connect to libvirt qemu:///system.

error from service: CheckAuthorization: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

Libvirt URI is: qemu:///system

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1036, in _do_open
        self._backend.open(self._do_creds_password)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/connection.py", line 144, in open
        open_flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 104, in openAuth
        if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
libvirtError: error from service: CheckAuthorization: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

Comment: Do you want the Live to boot when you reboot the VM or the actual host system?

Comment: Live boot when I reboot the VM.  Simply boot from the Live

Comment: Does your username belong to group libvirt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Plug the USB stick in to the host system and check it mounts
2. Open the VM - don't start it
3. Click the information button
4. Choose USB Redirector 1 and click Add Hardware
5. In the HW list under USB Host Device choose your USB stick
6. Click Finish
7. Click Boot Options
8. Enable the USB stick and move it to the top of the list

When you start the VM it boots from the USB as expected.

Under Boot device order you also have SATA CDROM 1. Instead of using USB stick, you can just load the ISO file directly to the virtual CDROM and mark it to be first in boot order. Using both methods my VM booted correctly, installer started and I was able to proceed with it. I didn't go through as didn't want to wipe my Win 10 VM.

I noted down exactly what steps I took. Maybe the USB doesn't need to be mounted - mine did automatically and I didn't bother umounting it. USB Redirector 2 also probably works just as well.

Comment: ugh.. well something went wrong.  I'm in a worse position now then before.  I pasted the output in the thread above because it was too long to post in this field.